# Calculate Duration between dates grouped by items in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I cannot seem to figure out how to calculate the duration between dates based on the stage of an order. You can see the columns below with an order number that goes through various stages each with its own creation date_time. I'd like a formula that can be applied to hundreds of rows so I can see how long each stage takes for each order grouped by username and then to average this out over all orders, can anyone help?

[image]

Here is a sample sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UeZzZx5uJQippBk-U4eVG_-Fl0jUIzwsutsUTLFS0xo/edit?usp=sharing

I've tried this query, but without success:

```
={QUERY(A1:J,"Select F, avg(J) where A is not null group by F pivot D"),QUERY(A1:J,"select avg(J) where A is not null group by F Label avg(J) 'Average'");TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:J,"Select avg(J) where A is not null group by D label avg(J) 'Total'")),QUERY(A1:J,"Select avg(J) where A is not null group by F label avg(J) ''")}
```

Comment: just added an example, thanks.

Comment: @player0 I've added a column to calculate the duration between the dates in column J and added a query but maybe you can see where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved this issue with this query:

```
={QUERY(A1:J,"Select F, avg(J) 
where J is not null 
group by F 
pivot D")
,
QUERY(A1:J,"select avg(J) 
where J is not null 
group by F 
Label avg(J) 'User Average'")
;
TRANSPOSE(QUERY(A1:J,"Select avg(J) 
where J is not null 
group by D 
label avg(J) 'Stage Average'"))
,
QUERY(A1:J,"Select avg(J) 
where J is not null 
label avg(J) ''")}
```